# Different text color each item of listview when populating using simple adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i'm trying to set different text color of each item inside the listview when populating the item like the pict below, but i can't make it work,

the idea is if the number of "Rata-Rata" exceed 75 then the text color will be set to black, but if below it will be set to red.

[image]

here's my code, i'm overriding the getview method :

```js
calonSiswa.add(map);
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(SeleksiNilai.this,
  calonSiswa,
  R.layout.activity_seleksi_nilai_single_item_view,
  new String[] {
    TAG_NO_URUTAN, TAG_NO_PENDAFTARAN,
    TAG_NAMA_LENGKAP, TAG_JURUSAN,
    TAG_RATA_RATA_NILAI, TAG_CARA_SELEKSI
  },
  new int[] {
    R.id.nomorUrutan, R.id.noPendaftar,
      R.id.namaPendaftar, R.id.jurusanPendaftar,
      R.id.rataRataNilai, R.id.caraSeleksi
  }) {
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView,
    ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView,
      parent);
    float ratarata = Float.parseFloat(rata_rata);
    int posisi = position;
    int textColorId = R.color.black;
    TextView text;
    text = (TextView) view
      .findViewById(R.id.noPendaftar);

    if (ratarata <= 75) {
      textColorId = R.color.red;
    } else if (ratarata >= 75) {
      textColorId = R.color.black;
    }
    text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
      textColorId));
    return view;
  }
};
```

here's another pict if i change the order from lowest to highest number, it seems the problem is whenever the last number exceed or below 75, it will change all item color inside listview, not the specific position
[image]

here's the complete code :

```js
private class GetData extends AsyncTask < String, String, JSONObject > {
  private ProgressDialog pDialog;
  String nomor, no_pendaftaran, nama_lengkap, jurusan, rata_rata, cara_seleksi;

  @
  Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    noPendaftaran = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noPendaftar);
    namaPendaftar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namaPendaftar);
    statusProses = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rataRataNilai);
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SeleksiNilai.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();

  }

  @
  Override
  protected JSONObject doInBackground(String...args) {

    // Getting JSON from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    return json;
  }

  @
  Override
  protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
    try {
      // Getting JSON Array from URL
      pendaftar = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);

      for (int i = 0; i < pendaftar.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = pendaftar.getJSONObject(i);

        // Storing JSON item in a Variable
        nomor = String.valueOf(i + 1);
        no_pendaftaran = c.getString(TAG_NO_PENDAFTARAN);
        nama_lengkap = c.getString(TAG_NAMA_LENGKAP);
        jurusan = c.getString(TAG_JURUSAN);
        rata_rata = c.getString(TAG_RATA_RATA_NILAI);
        cara_seleksi = c.getString(TAG_CARA_SELEKSI);

        // Adding value HashMap key => value

        HashMap < String, String > map = new HashMap < String, String > ();

        map.put(TAG_NO_URUTAN, nomor);
        map.put(TAG_NO_PENDAFTARAN, no_pendaftaran);
        map.put(TAG_NAMA_LENGKAP, nama_lengkap);
        map.put(TAG_JURUSAN, jurusan);
        map.put(TAG_RATA_RATA_NILAI, rata_rata);
        map.put(TAG_CARA_SELEKSI, cara_seleksi);
        /*map.put(TAG_STATUS_PROSES, status_proses);*/

        calonSiswa.add(map);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
          SeleksiNilai.this, calonSiswa,
          R.layout.activity_seleksi_nilai_single_item_view,
          new String[] {
            TAG_NO_URUTAN, TAG_NO_PENDAFTARAN, TAG_NAMA_LENGKAP, TAG_JURUSAN, TAG_RATA_RATA_NILAI, TAG_CARA_SELEKSI
          },
          new int[] {
            R.id.nomorUrutan, R.id.noPendaftar, R.id.namaPendaftar, R.id.jurusanPendaftar, R.id.rataRataNilai, R.id.caraSeleksi
          }) {@
          Override
          public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            float ratarata = Float.parseFloat(rata_rata);
            int posisi = position;
            int textColorId = R.color.black;
            TextView text;
            text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.noPendaftar);

            if (ratarata <= 75) {
              textColorId = R.color.red;
            } else if (ratarata >= 75) {
              textColorId = R.color.black;
            }
            text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(textColorId));
            return view;
          }
        };

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

      }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: where is your `rata_rata` from?

Comment: @alijandro fetch it from database, via php.

Comment: have you solved your problem? @WandaTeng

Comment: @Mano nope, still unable to solve this, any suggestion?
the problem is whenever the last item of ratarata value exceed or below 75, it will change all the item color, not the specific position, i was trying to get the position but couldn't get a clue how to do it.

Comment: don,t add textcolorid  as black,first check the condititon then put value

Comment: use if and else...! don,t go If ,else if

Comment: @Mano not affecting at all.

the else if not even a problem, you can see my pic above when i change the item order from highest to lowest and lowest to highest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82161/discussion-between-mano-and-wanda-teng).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get "rata_rata" by position in getView().

`rata_rata = calonSiswa.get(position).get(TAG_RATA_RATA_NILAI);`

Answer (score 0):

```
 int textColorId;
   TextView text; //add this lines in global 

    @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                float ratarata = Float.parseFloat(rata_rata);
                int posisi = position;


                text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.noPendaftar);

                if (ratarata <= 75)
                {
                  textColorId = R.color.red;
                } else {
                  textColorId = R.color.black;
                }
                text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(textColorId));
                return view;
              }
            };
```

Answer (score -1):

that's obvious, your call the setAdapter method in the loop, the value of ratarata is always the last one

Comment: already move the setAdapter outside the loop, but the nothing change

Comment: @WandaTeng not the setAdapter, move new Adapter code outside,ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter

Comment: update your code please, have you print the ratarata value in logcat?

Answer (score -1):

**try this way may help u**

```
 @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView,
              parent);

            text1 =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.noPendaftar);



             if (ratarata <= 75) {
                  textColorId = R.color.red;
                  text1.setTextColor(textColorId);
                } else if (ratarata >= 75) {
                  textColorId = R.color.black;
                  text1.setTextColor(textColorId);
                }

             //set the tag of position
            view.setTag(position);
            return view;
          }
        };
```

Comment: its not working, but this problem is solved, thank you anyway.

Answer (score -1):

the problem solved, thanks to situee, get the rata_rata value using

rata_rata = calonSiswa.get(position).get(TAG_RATA_RATA_NILAI);

so here's the code :

```js
@
Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
  pDialog.dismiss();
  try {
    // Getting JSON Array from URL
    pendaftar = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);

    for (int i = 0; i < pendaftar.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject c = pendaftar.getJSONObject(i);


      // Storing JSON item in a Variable
      nomor = String.valueOf(i + 1);
      no_pendaftaran = c.getString(TAG_NO_PENDAFTARAN);
      nama_lengkap = c.getString(TAG_NAMA_LENGKAP);
      jurusan = c.getString(TAG_JURUSAN);
      rata_rata = c.getString(TAG_RATA_RATA_NILAI);
      cara_seleksi = c.getString(TAG_CARA_SELEKSI);


      // Adding value HashMap key => value

      HashMap < String, String > map = new HashMap < String, String > ();

      map.put(TAG_NO_URUTAN, nomor);
      map.put(TAG_NO_PENDAFTARAN, no_pendaftaran);
      map.put(TAG_NAMA_LENGKAP, nama_lengkap);
      map.put(TAG_JURUSAN, jurusan);
      map.put(TAG_RATA_RATA_NILAI, rata_rata);
      map.put(TAG_CARA_SELEKSI, cara_seleksi);

      calonSiswa.add(map);
      ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


      adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        SeleksiNilai.this, calonSiswa,
        R.layout.activity_seleksi_nilai_single_item_view,
        new String[] {
          TAG_NO_URUTAN, TAG_NO_PENDAFTARAN, TAG_NAMA_LENGKAP, TAG_JURUSAN, TAG_RATA_RATA_NILAI, TAG_CARA_SELEKSI
        },
        new int[] {
          R.id.nomorUrutan, R.id.noPendaftar, R.id.namaPendaftar, R.id.jurusanPendaftar, R.id.rataRataNilai, R.id.caraSeleksi
        }) {
        
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
          
          //HERE I ADD THE CODE FROM situee
          String rata_rata1 = calonSiswa.get(position).get(TAG_RATA_RATA_NILAI);
          float ratarata = Float.parseFloat(rata_rata1);
          //////////////////////////
          
          int textColorId;
          TextView text;
          text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.noPendaftar);

          if (ratarata <= 75) {
            textColorId = R.color.red;
          } else {
            textColorId = R.color.black;
          }
          text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(textColorId));
          return view;
        }

      };
      list.setAdapter(adapter);
      list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @
        Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent,
          View view, int position, long id) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          noPendaftaranTerpilih = calonSiswa.get(position).get("no_pendaftaran");
          Intent i = new Intent(SeleksiNilai.this, SeleksiNilaiLanjutan.class);
          startActivity(i);

          /*Toast.makeText(SeleksiNilai.this,"You Clicked at "+ calonSiswa.get(position).get("no_pendaftaran"),
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

        }
      });
    }

  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```

it works like a charm, thanks everyone.

[image]